# Unable to start passenger on freebsd

Tags: nginx, passenger, freebsd

I receive this error message
nginx: [alert] Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog: it seems to have been killed with signal SIGSEGV during startup (-1: Unknown error)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there has been a problem with passenger on FreeBSD 11.2:

https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/2097

Comment: I'm running passenger/nginx-module on freebsd 11.2 now Everything works fine The thread at the link above is a little complex for me to delve into right now since mine works However,  my 11.2 install is an upgrade not a fresh install so these users may have had their issues with the latter I've been running web and mail servers on  freebsd installed beater boxes for many years Never ran X-Window though